# JMeter test from Java Code - Generate Console/File Reports matching GUI Reports

Tags: java, performance, jmeter

I run the jmx file from Java code and would like to get console/file reports.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("path/jmeter.properties");
    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("path/jmeter");
    JMeterUtils.initLocale();

    SaveService.loadProperties();

    File in = new File("test.jmx");
    HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);

    Summariser summer = null;
    String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
    if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
        summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
    }
    String logFile = "result.html";
    ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
    logger.setFilename(logFile);
    testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

    jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
    jmeter.run();

    ReportGenerator generator = new ReportGenerator(logFile, null);
    generator.generate();
}
```

Running this code I have a html file generated:

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1632316570010,1745,Created,500,,Requests 1-1,text,false,,417,1228,1,1,https://my.url,1740,0,1371
```

But for example I need the report like on GUI - Aggregate Graph:
[image]

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:** Running into Null Pointer exception with this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("bla/jmeter.properties");
    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("bla/apache-jmeter-5.4.1");
    JMeterUtils.initLocale();

    File reportOutputDir = new File("report-output");
    if (reportOutputDir.exists()) {
        FileUtils.forceDelete(reportOutputDir);
    }

    File results = new File("result.html");
    if (results.exists()) {
        FileUtils.forceDelete(results);
    }

    JMeterUtils.setProperty("jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.classname", "org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter");
    JMeterUtils.setProperty("jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.property.output_dir","report-output\\dashboard");

    SaveService.loadProperties();

    HashTree testPlanTree = new ListedHashTree();

    HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
    httpSampler.setDomain("host");
    httpSampler.setPort(443);
    httpSampler.setPath("/api/v1/stock-count/created");
    httpSampler.setMethod("POST");

    LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
    loopController.setLoops(1);
    loopController.addTestElement(httpSampler);
    loopController.setFirst(true);
    loopController.initialize();

    ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
    threadGroup.setNumThreads(10);
    threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
    threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
    threadGroup.initialize();

    TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan();
    testPlan.addThreadGroup(threadGroup);

    String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
    Summariser summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
    ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
    logger.setFilename("result.html");

    testPlanTree.add(testPlan, logger);

    jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
    jmeter.run();

    ReportGenerator generator = new ReportGenerator("result.html", null);
    generator.generate();
}
```

15:39:26.906 [main] INFO org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter - Creating statistics for overall
15:39:26.906 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter - Creating statistics for result data:null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter.createStatistic(JsonExporter.java:121)
at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter.export(JsonExporter.java:72)
at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.exportData(ReportGenerator.java:379)
at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:257)
at com.nordstrom.inventory.test.api.passport.JMeterTest.main(JMeterTest.java:87)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0. It's not "html", it's JMeter's [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) in [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format.
1. If you want to see the "Aggregate Graph" - Open your `result.html` file using "Browse" button of the [Aggregate Graph](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Graph) listener and it will load it and render the chart
2. You might also want to consider using i.e. [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line/) which allows generation of various tables/charts from command line (can be also done programatically if you have the .jars in your project [CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html))
3. You might want to generate JMeter's [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), you're almost there, you just need to add a couple of lines to your script somewhere before test execution:

   ```
   JMeterUtils.setProperty("jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.classname", "org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter");
   JMeterUtils.setProperty("jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.property.output_dir","report-output/dashboard");
   ```

   and then go to `report-output\dashboard` folder and open `index.html` with your favourite browser.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! That worked for me, Dashboard looks awesome, but I need one improvement regarding this. I've noticed that This dashboard aggregates every launch - how can I overwrite the Dashboard every single run ?

Comment: If you want "fresh" results you need to delete the .jtl results file, i.e. something like `new File("result.html").delete()` somewhere in the beginning of your `main()` function.

Comment: I've edited the question. now I'm trying to configure jmx file in Java Code instead of load existing file. And I'm running into exception. Please take a look what could e wrong.